# how to solve error for object double free set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i am doing is placing a button and while clicking the button it will display the image and i need to change the image for each button click for i am  writing if loop like

```
if(counter[button.tag] = 2) { [images exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:1 ]; }
```

but images are not exchanged it shows like this in console

```
error for object double free set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

how can i solve this. i did n't understand what is this problem why it comes pls help me. thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to use the Zombie Instrument tool to check if a zombie object has been messaged. Go to File>New in Instruments and choose Zombie, then run you executable until it will crash. At that point the tool shall link to you the object involved and you will be able to have a look at its history.